# Transform list item in Create New Item workflow

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, office-365, column

I have a workflow that creates a new list item in List B when a new item is added to Liast A. I use a simple Create Item in ____ (Output to Variable: Create) workflow.

I want to change the value of certain fields when I create the new item. For example, a column in List A has a Boolean type, but when I set the value for that field in List B I want it to be a Single Line of Text that is blank if the value was False.

Is this possible?

Thank you